# Find the minimum even number in a list recursively

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I've written this function:

```
struct nodo * MinimoPariListaRic(struct nodo * top) {
  struct nodo * minimo_p = NULL; //this should be the minimum even number

  //list have one or no one element
  if(top) {
    if(!top->next) 
        if(top->valore % 2 == 0) return top; // valore(italian) = value
        else return NULL;
  }
  else return NULL;


  if(top->next)
    minimo_p = MinimoPariListaRic(top->next);

  if (top->valore % 2 == 0)
  {
     if(minimo_p->valore < top->valore) return minimo_p;
     else return top;
  }
  else return minimo_p;
}
```

If the list's elements are all even, the function will return the minimum, and it's ok.
But if an odd number appears, the function doesn't work correctly.
If all the numbers are odd, function should return NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your algorithm is wrong, you can have an undefined behavior if the recursive call return NULL because setting *minimo_p* to *NULL* and you will dereference it if `(top->valore % 2 == 0)`, and it is too much complicated, you do not need a recursive call, just to go throw the list, for instance :

```
struct nodo * MinimoPariListaRic(struct nodo * l) {
  struct nodo * minimo_p = NULL; //this should be the minium even number

  while (l != NULL) {
    if (l->valore % 2 == 0) {
      if ((minimo_p == NULL) || (l->valore < minimo_p->valore))
        minimo_p = l;
    }
    l = l->next;
  }

  return minimo_p;
}
```

Because your edited topic requires a recursive call you can do for instance :

```
struct nodo * MinimoPariListaRic(struct nodo * l) {
  if (l == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else {
    struct nodo * minimo_p = MinimoPariListaRic(l->next);

    return ((l->valore % 2 == 0) &&
            ((minimo_p == NULL) || (l->valore < minimo_p->valore)))
       ? l :  minimo_p;
  }
}
```

as you can see this is simple, I check only one times in the program if *valore* is odd or not etc

---

using a full program to check :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo {
  struct nodo * next;
  int valore;
};

struct nodo * MinimoPariListaRic(struct nodo * l) {
  if (l == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else {
    struct nodo * minimo_p = MinimoPariListaRic(l->next);

    return ((l->valore % 2 == 0) &&
            ((minimo_p == NULL) || (l->valore < minimo_p->valore)))
       ? l :  minimo_p;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  /* make a list from the args */
  struct nodo * l = NULL;
  
  while (argc > 1) {
    struct nodo * r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    
    r->next = l;
    if (sscanf(argv[--argc], "%d", &r->valore) != 1) {
      puts("invalid number");
      return 0;
    }
    l = r;
  }
  
  /* show list well made */

  struct nodo * ll;
  
  for (ll = l; ll != NULL; ll = ll->next)
    printf("%d ", ll->valore);
  putchar('\n');
  
  /* */
  
  ll = MinimoPariListaRic(l);
  
  if (ll == NULL)
    puts("no even value");
  else
    printf("min even value is %d\n", ll->valore);
  
  /* free resources */

  while (l) {
    ll = l->next;
    free(l);
    l = ll;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1 4 2 7 8
1 4 2 7 8 
min even value is 2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

no even value
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 3
3 
no even value
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 3 3 1 5
3 3 1 5 
no even value
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out 3 4 5 2 0
==16881== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16881== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16881== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16881== Command: ./a.out 3 4 5 2 0
==16881== 
3 4 5 2 0 
min even value is 0
==16881== 
==16881== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16881==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16881==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,064 bytes allocated
==16881== 
==16881== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16881== 
==16881== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==16881== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I have already done the iterative version, and yes, is very very simple, i know. 
The "challenge" was to turn it into a recursive function.

Comment: @LuigiV. why you did not say in your question it must be recursive ?

Comment: @LuigiV. I edited my answer to add an other proposal using recursion

Comment: what does mean `? l :  minimo_p;` ?

Comment: @LuigiV. the form `(test) : st1 : st2` values the value of  *st1* if *test* is true else *st2*, so to do `return (test) : st1 : st2;` is same as `type r; if (test) r = st1; else r = st2; return r;` but the first form is more concise and readable

Comment: @LuigiV. I edited my answer to put a full program to check that works

Comment: @LuigiV. I did two times the same typo in a previous remark, I wanted to say : the form `(test) ? st1 : st2` values the value of *st1* if *test* is true else *st2*, so to do `return (test) ? st1 : st2;` is same as `type r; if (test) r = st1; else r = st2; return r;` but the first form is more concise and readable

Comment: Thanks a lot fot this example, it helped me and now I understand the form `(test) ? st1 : st2`. However, I immediately tried and implemented your function in my program!

Answer (score 3):

Because minimo_p can be NULL after the function returns from recursion if the list contains an **odd integer at the last position** and **at least one even integer anywhere**.

This line is erroneous:

```
if(minimo_p->valore < top->valore) return minimo_p;
```

You can just add the null condition here:

```
if(minimo_p && minimo_p->valore < top->valore) return minimo_p;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have to use recursion you should try write this down in pseudo language first:

- if current list has only one element

  - -> return it if even, else return null
- if list has more elements

  - get minimum of rest of list
  - if current element is odd

    - return the rest-minimum
  - else if rest is null

    - return this element
  - else if rest is not null

    - return the smaller one

I would not go with recusion on this. With really long lists you will crash your stack.

A simple loop would be even simpler and less mind bending:

- init minimum to NULL
- init iterator with list
- while iterator != Null

  - if iterator even and minimum == Null

    - minimum = iterator
  - else if even and iterator < minimum

    - minimum = iterator
  - advance iterator

Answer (score 0):

My five cents. I have also included a recursive function that finds the node with the maximum even value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct nodo
{
    int valore;
    struct nodo *next;
};

int push_front( struct nodo **top, int valore )
{
    struct nodo *nodo_nuovo  = malloc( sizeof( struct nodo ) );
    int success = nodo_nuovo != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        nodo_nuovo->valore = valore;
        nodo_nuovo->next = *top;
        *top = nodo_nuovo;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( struct nodo *top, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; top != NULL; top = top->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", top->valore );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

struct nodo * MinimoPariListaRic( struct nodo * top )
{
    if ( !top )
    {
        return top;
    }
    else
    {
        struct nodo *minimo = MinimoPariListaRic( top->next );
        
        
        if ( minimo == NULL )
        {
            minimo = top->valore % 2 == 0 ? top : minimo;
        }
        else if ( top->valore % 2 == 0 )
        {
            minimo = minimo->valore < top->valore ? minimo : top;
        }

        return minimo;
    }
}

struct nodo * MassimoPariListaRic( struct nodo * top )
{
    if ( !top )
    {
        return top;
    }
    else
    {
        struct nodo *massimo = MassimoPariListaRic( top->next );
        
        
        if ( massimo == NULL )
        {
            massimo = top->valore % 2 == 0 ? top : massimo;
        }
        else if ( top->valore % 2 == 0 )
        {
            massimo = top->valore < massimo->valore ? massimo : top;
        }

        return massimo;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct nodo *top = NULL;
    enum { N = 10 };
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &top, rand() % N );     
    }

    fputc( '\n', display( top, stdout ) );
    
    struct nodo *minimo = MinimoPariListaRic( top );
    
    if ( minimo != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Minimo pari valore is %d\n", minimo->valore );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "there is no minimo pari valore" );
    }
    
    struct nodo *massimo = MassimoPariListaRic( top );
    
    if ( massimo != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Massimo pari valore is %d\n", massimo->valore );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "there is no massimo pari valore" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
8 -> 9 -> 9 -> 9 -> 7 -> 9 -> 7 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> null
Minimo pari valore is 2
Massimo pari valore is 8
```

As for your function definition then you need to check whether the pointer
`minimo_p` returned by the call

```
  if(top->next)
    minimo_p = MinimoPariListaRic(top->next);
```

is equal to NULL in the next if statement

```
  if (top->valore % 2 == 0)
  {
     if(minimo_p->valore < top->valore) return minimo_p;
     else return top;
  }
```